# addObject for one/many-to-many relationships in core data for iPhone

Tags: iphone, core-data, insert

I have the following 2 Entity’s in my xcdatamodel:

1. Matrix
   1.1 Attributes
   Name
   1.2 Relationships
   MatrixToProcess
   The Destination is: Process
   The Inverse is: ProcessToMatrix
   The To-Many Relationship is checked
   The Delete Rule is Cascade
2. Process
   2.1 Attributes
   Name
   2.2 Relationships
   ProcessToMatrix
   The Destination is: Matrix
   The Inverse is: MatrixToProcess
   The To-Many Relationship is not checked
   The Delete Rule is Nullify

I can successfully add a new Matrix, which is added and shows up correctly in the UITableView.

I can successfully add a new Process, however,
All necessary information is added to the database with the EXCEPTION of the Z_PK value from the Matrix table.
i.e. The sqlite database in the iPhone simulator will create the new Process Name, but does NOT enter any information into the ZPROCESSTOMATRIX column. If I manually insert the associated Matrix Name Z_PK value, everything works.

I am struggling with. don't fully understand how to add the addObject under the Process *newProcess = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Process" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];.
This is the code I am using:

```
- (void)addProcess:(id)sender {
    ProcessAddViewController *addController = [[ProcessAddViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProcessAddView" bundle:nil];
    addController.delegate = self;  
    Process *newProcess = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Process" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    addController.process = newProcess;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addController];
    [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];    
    [navigationController release];
    [addController release];
}

- (void)processAddViewController:(ProcessAddViewController *)processAddViewController didAddProcess:(Process *)process {
    if (process) {        
        [self showProcess:process animated:NO];
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


- (void)showProcess:(Process *)process animated:(BOOL)animated {
    RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    rootViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;    
    if(entitySearchPredicate == nil)
    {
        NSMutableArray* mutableFetchResults = [CoreDataHelper getObjectsFromContext:self.entityName :@"displayOrder" :YES :managedObjectContext];       
        [self setEntityArray:mutableFetchResults];
        [mutableFetchResults release];
    }
    else
    {
        NSMutableArray* mutableFetchResults = [CoreDataHelper searchObjectsInContext:self.entityName :entitySearchPredicate :@"displayOrder" :YES :managedObjectContext];
        [self setEntityArray:mutableFetchResults];
        [mutableFetchResults release];
    }
    [rootViewController release];
}
```

Any help and/or direction will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the relationship between the new Process and the Matrix.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738676/iphone-core-data-inserting-new-objects-question/1741073#1741073) to [iphone core data inserting new objects question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738676/iphone-core-data-inserting-new-objects-question).

**UPDATE**

Assuming that you have generated the class files for Process and Matrix AND Process has a relationship to Matrix named "processToMatrix", the code to set the relationship would be:

```
newProcess.processToMatrix = matrix;
```

where "matrix" the the Matrix object that should be associated with the new Process object.

Comment: I have set the relationship in the xcdatamodel. Is there something I need to add in code to set this relationship between the new Process and Matrix. 
I appologize for the vagueness but I am new to iphone development.
I appreciate your response.

Comment: What gets me stunned is the [Airport.Board.flights addObject:newFlight]; line. What would I need to have in this line.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you need (except you would be adding a Matrix object to that set in your new Process object). The first step is to generate the Class files from the data model.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I have
Matrix.h
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Process;

@interface Matrix :  NSManagedObject  
{
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * Name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * displayOrder;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet* MatrixToProcess;

@end


@interface Matrix (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
- (void)addMatrixToProcessObject:(Process *)value;
- (void)removeMatrixToProcessObject:(Process *)value;
- (void)addMatrixToProcess:(NSSet *)value;
- (void)removeMatrixToProcess:(NSSet *)value;

@end

Comment: Matrix.m
#import "Matrix.h"

#import "Process.h"

@implementation Matrix 

@dynamic Name;
@dynamic displayOrder;
@dynamic MatrixToProcess;

@end

Comment: Process.h
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Objective;
@class Matrix;

@interface Process :  NSManagedObject  
{
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * Name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * displayOrder;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet* ProcessToObjective;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Matrix * ProcessToMatrix;

@end

Comment: @interface Process (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
- (void)addProcessToObjectiveObject:(Objective *)value;
- (void)removeProcessToObjectiveObject:(Objective *)value;
- (void)addProcessToObjective:(NSSet *)value;
- (void)removeProcessToObjective:(NSSet *)value;

@end
Process.m
#import "Process.h"

#import "Objective.h"
#import "Matrix.h"

@implementation Process 

@dynamic Name;
@dynamic displayOrder;
@dynamic ProcessToObjective;
@dynamic ProcessToMatrix;

@end

Comment: Can you delete these comments with code? There are not useful. If you have more code, edit your original question and add it there. Also, you may to format your question's code so that it is readable.

Comment: I just realized that you have a to-one relationship from Process to Matrix (rather than to-many), so you just need to set that property to the appropriate Matrix object (rather than adding the Matrix object to a set).

Comment: Would this code be correct? Specifically the line for:[self setValue:Process forKey:@"Matrix"];

Process *newProcess = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Process" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
 [self setValue:Process forKey:@"Matrix"];

Comment: It would be more like (assuming the Matrix object is named "matrix"): newProcess.ProcessToMatrix = matrix

Comment: Again, can you PLEASE delete these comments with code? They are not useful. If you have more code, edit your original question and add it there. Also, PLEASE fix the formatting of the code in your question!