# Using a Core Data data model to instantiate new objects

Tags: iphone, core-data, attributes, entity, datamodel

basically i have this iphone application that fetches data about different modules (subjects studied by student) from the applications sqlite database (from entity: module) and displays them in a uitableview.. at the moment when you click on a cell (that represents a module), it pushes a viewcontroller that contains details of the module.

**'Module' attributes:** name = module name, body = notes that user can save for the module.

i have added an assessment entity and its attributes are:

**'Assessment' attributes:** type = exam or assignment, name = name of assignment, data = date that it is due
[image: Core Data Datamodel]

What i want to do is:

1. Ask the user how many assessments they have for a specific module (e.g. "how many aassessments do you have for 'module a'?"
2. And then the user would say a number (e.g. 3), then the application should somehow add e.g. 3, assessments and show information (i.e. textfields etc) for each assessment in the module view page (that gets pushed when user selects a module)

If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated.. Also apologies if my explanation is a bit confusing..

Comment: Could you add a bit of detail on what you have already tried and what, if anything, is not working?

Comment: 1 i could probably figure out how to do.. and therefore not so critical.. it is only there to give an idea of where the app gets the number of assessments from.. but number 2 however seems to be tricky.. im having difficulty understanding how i would generate (for example) 3 entities automatically i havent tried anything as im not sure how to go about it..

Comment: Can I suggest that you change your title to something like "Using a Core Data data model to instantiate new objects" (If I've understood correctly)?

Comment: The only pointer I have is to look at Apple's doc here, which says: You typically create a managed object using a convenience method—insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:—of NSEntityDescription, which returns a properly initialized instance of the correct class for the entity you specify, inserted into the managed object context. (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Articles/04_Adding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008305-CH106-SW1)

Comment: Finally, check out this question, which might be the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738676/iphone-core-data-inserting-new-objects-question

Comment: Thank you for the information martin.. i shall look into doing it that way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you want to put an inverse relationship in from assessment back to module.

then you can create the module objects,

```
for(int i=0;i<userInputValue;i++){
    AssessmentObject *anAssessment=     [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Assesment" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [anAssessment setDate:[NSDate date]];
    [anAssessment setName:@"Untitled module"];
    [anAssessment setModule:self.currentModule];

}
```

once they have been allocated then you need to push them to the modal view to control input

```
ModalViewController *aModalViewController=[[ModalViewController alloc] init];
aModalViewController.assessmentSet = [self.currentModule assessments];
[self.navigationController pushModalViewController:aModalViewController animated:YES];
```

you would then need to setup the modalViewController to allow editing of the objects in a set. maybe some next/previous buttons, and then get it to save the context when dismissed.
[image: How the entities should look]

Comment: the way i was looking at it is, there can be many assessments to one module. so im thinking it would be: modules 'one to many" assessments.. would that be correct? and is that the same as your inverse relationship?
p.s. thankyou for answering :)

Comment: you have your one to many relationship set up properly, there would be one module which has many assessments, but for core data house keeping and also for your own convenience you want to set up so that you can find out which module owns the assessment, which would be the inverse relationship.

Comment: I have edited the answer to show how you should have your entities set up. hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) 
I will try this and let you know what happens